Identify this Movie or Horror Anthology Segment Airing on USA in the mid to late 1980's
The premise of the story is that a young woman in an apartment building has suspicions that her new neighbor has murdered his wife (neighbors are an older man and woman).  There are scenes where the neighbor is dragging his wife's dead body down a corridor in a trunk.  The (murdered) wife had a pet - a bird, I believe?  He'd killed that, too.  The woman's husband does not believe her and is convinced that she's dreaming.  The final twist is that it's been a dream/timewarp, because the last scene shows a real estate agent bringing a couple to look at the young couple's apartment and it's the couple from the dream/visions.  This has been driving me crazy for decades because I would've watched it as a kid in the 80's, and I feel like it would have been on USA Saturday Nightmares.
